# Derivative of $e^{x}$ by definition

Tags: limits

if you plug in $e^{x}$ into the definition of a derivative, you'll end up with

the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h-1}}{h}$. This limit is a ''standard limit'' and equals 1.

However if i wouldnt know this is a standard limit that equals 1, but use a taylor series instead to evaluate that limit, would that be justified? because the coefficient of a taylor series of a function involves a derivative, you're making use of something that you actually dont know yet (namely the derivative of $e^{x}$)

So the question is: is a taylor series justified to use in the definition of a derivative?

Comment: How is $e^x$ defined in your context?

Comment: an exponential function with base e

Comment: And then how is $a^x$ defined?

Comment: @OdellBeckhamJr Taylor's formula requires the computation of derivatives of the exponential... and you want to deduce the derivative of the exponential...

Comment: And how is $e$ defined?

Comment: The usual definition of the exponential function is done as a power series or as the inverse function of the integral over $1/x$.  Which one do you prefer?

Comment: Does this answer to your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359023/using-the-limit-definition-to-find-the-derivative-of-ex

Comment: @PierreCarre yeah, my question is: is it justified to use a taylor series?

Comment: @VIVID no ,,,,,

Comment: You can define the exponential function via $\exp(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n/n! $ and then prove that $\exp(x+y) =\exp(x) \exp(y) $ and $\exp'(x) =\exp(x) $. Using these one proves that it can work as an exponential $e^x$ where $e=\exp(1)$ and further that the original defining series indeed equals its Taylor series. There is no circularity involved here. And this is one of easier approaches to theory of exponential function.

Comment: By the way any definition you choose for the exponential function should allow you to prove all the properties without any circularity. And it is better to know multiple approaches.

Comment: I guess the question is not *specifically* about $e^x$ but in general about $a^x$.

Comment: This might help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491220/show-lim-h-to-0-fracah-1h-exists-without-lh%c3%b4pital-or-even-referenc

Answer (score 1):

If you define the exponential as $\displaystyle e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, and differentiate term by term (you can prove this is ok...) you get
$$
(e^x)' = \left(1+x+x^2/2 + x^3/3! + \cdots\right)' = 1+x+x^2/2 +x^3/3! + \cdots) = e^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I approach these topics. (i) Define a function $\exp:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by
$$\exp(x)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$ (ii) Differentiate this defining equation to prove that $$\exp'(x)=\exp(x)$$(iii) Define $$e=\exp(1).$$ (iv) Prove $$\exp(x)=e^x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R.$$ (v) Prove that 
$$e=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the limit says;
$$f^\prime (x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Given that we care considering $f(x)=e^x$ then $f(x+h)=e^{x+h}$.Substituting this into the expression;
$$f^\prime (x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}$$
This can be simplified;
$$f^\prime (x)= e^{x}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(e^h-1)}{h}$$
Refer to;
[How to prove that $\lim_{h\to 0} \, \frac{e^h-1}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832934/how-to-prove-that-lim-h-to-0-fraceh-1h)
Then;
$$f^\prime (x)= e^{x}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(e^h-1)}{h}=e^x \times 1$$
And thus;
$$f^\prime(x)=e^x$$

Comment: Doesn't l'Hopital use the derivative that you are trying to proof?

Comment: @MATHBOI You took a long walk to get to the same spot!

Comment: Modified my response @GyroGearloose Thank you!

Comment: i know that that limit equals 1. but my question is: if you use a taylor series to evaluate that limit, would that be valid, since a taylor series makes use of a derivative itself. you're basically using something that you dont know yet