# Evaluate the common limit

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'd like more of an explanation than a solution, I'm sorry but I'm studying math again after 12 years, and I don't understand basic concepts.

I have to evaluate some limits without using L'Hopital rule, just by definition.
So I got:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to \:0}\left(\frac{e^h-1}{h}\right).$$

After evaluating it in a Math app, it states that it's just 1 due to the common limit evaluation, but I don't understand why it's 1.

Comment: [A useful link.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832934/how-to-prove-that-lim-h-to-0-fraceh-1h)

Comment: What's your definition of $e^h$? In any case, your limit is well-scrutinized [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359023/using-the-limit-definition-to-find-the-derivative-of-ex?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: One can develop a very good intuitive understanding of $e^h$ for small $h$ by noticing that $1+h$ is a fantastic approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what your definition of
$e^h$ is.

If you know the power series
($e^h
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{h^n}{n!}$),
it is easy.

If you know that
$(e^h)' = e^h$,
then
$e^h-1
=\int_0^h e^x dx
$,
and you can use the mean value theorem
combined with $e^0=1$
and the continuity of $e^h$
to get the result.

There are probably a few other ways,
but these occurred to me.

Comment: Even easier, by definition the derivative of $e^h$ at $h=0$ is the desired limit.

Comment: Very true. It's nice when problems have lots of different solutions.